# Reauthenticate user with Facebook

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am using Flutter to create a mobile application. I am using Firebase for authentication. My user logs in with Facebook.  The user should reauthenticate him/her self when deleting the account.  The documentation talks about reauthentication using email and password like this:

```
// Create a credential
EmailAuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(email: email, password: password);

// Reauthenticate
await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential);
```

Since the user does not have an email and password but rather he is logged in with Facebook, I should reauthenticate the user with Facebook.  I searched the documentation for this but I had no luck.

Could some one be kind and tell me how to do that.

I tried to log the user in with Facebook (even though he is already logged in) but was not successful.  Her is what I tried:

```
FacebookLoginResult result = await FacebookLogin().logIn(permissions: [
  FacebookPermission.publicProfile,
  FacebookPermission.email,
]);

switch (result.status) {
  case FacebookLoginStatus.success:
    FacebookAccessToken? accessToken = result.accessToken;
    if (accessToken == null) {
      return null;
    }

    UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithCredential(
      FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessToken.token),
    );
    return userCredential;

  case FacebookLoginStatus.cancel:
    throw FirebaseAuthException(
      code: 'ERROR_FACEBOOK_LOGIN_FAILED',
      message: result.error?.developerMessage,
    );
  default:
    throw UnimplementedError();
}

await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.reauthenticateWithCredential(
  userCredential!.credential!,
);
```

Answer (score -1):

To get Authentication Credential with Google

```
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
scopes: <String>[
  'email',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
]);

 final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount =
    await _googleSignIn.signIn();
final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
    await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
  accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
  idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
);
```

To get Authentication Credential with Apple

```
final appleIdCredential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
  scopes: [
    AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
    AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
  ],
);
final AuthCredential appleCredential =
    OAuthProvider('apple.com').credential(
  accessToken: appleIdCredential.authorizationCode,
  idToken: appleIdCredential.identityToken,
);
```

Comment: Can you reauthenticate the user using your code if the user is already signed in with Google.  I am using the same code that you have up.  My user is already signed in but when I reauthenticate, I get error.  I am not sure why!!

Comment: I am not asking you how to authenticate with Google or Facebook.  I am asking how to REAUTHENTICATE using google or Facebook.  For example, the user is already logged in with Facebook and I need to delete the user so I need to reauthenticate the user with Facebook in order to delete the user.